What happens to kinetic energy that enters a black hole?
A little thought experiment:

We are in a space ship, safely orbiting black hole A.
We fetch 2 smaller, identical black holes, B and C and we position them on the opposite sides of black hole A.
We somehow accelerate(as opposed to just letting them fall) black holes B and C towards A, lets say to 99.99999% C from the reference frame of A.

So, as B and C simultaneously cross the event horizon of A from perfectly opposite sides and disappear into it, what will happen to the kinetic energy of B and C from going really really fast?
Would the mass of A increase only by the actual mass of B and C and their kinetic energies would be sort of hidden until the eventual evaporation of A?
Would we observe the total mass of A increasing by the mass equivalent of this kinetic energy in addition to the actual mass of B and C at the time when they pass through the event horizon?
Would the mass of A increase only by the actual mass of B and C at first, and the kinetic energy would manifest as additional mass some time later? Like if somehow B and C actually collided inside A at a later date, as observed from our space ship?
(Also lets pretend that there is no energy emanated away from A in the form of gravitational waves from this event, unless its important. When I say mass of A, I mean the total combined mass-any-kind-of-energy equivalent that we can measure from outside the black hole.)

Your use of the term "potential energy" seems odd. Did you mean kinetic energy?

I suppose yes, I mean kinetic energy

@user81993 edit the question accprdingly, then

At that speed, the Lorentz gamma factor is >2236.
